# Session variables losing value

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, session-variables

I am using session variables to store different pieces of information. The minute I redirect using javascript the session variables seem to lose their values. this happens very inconsistanly especialy in Chrome (other browsers are fine!)

```
window.location = "../submitOrder.php?custid="+custid;
```

(in the real code i put in the whole url)

then, starting from the submitOrder my session variables are blank...

what could be the cause of this? does it have to do with the redirect?

I don't mind adding more details of necessary, but the problem is a simple but confusing one.

Thank you!

Comment: How do you propagate your session IDs? Cookies? If so, check whether the new URL matches the cookie's path and domain restrictions.

Comment: thank you. I am a little bit of a beginner, can you explain more? the url is another page in the same site. how do I check that. I use session_start() on my pages

Comment: and it really only happens in Chrome, the first time I got on to the site. does chrome act differently with cookies?

Comment: btw, thank you for the quick response :)

Comment: It's probably a good idea to read up on how sessions work first. Anyway, you can easily check cookies in your browser; the cookie you're looking for is typically called phpsessid, and it should be valid for both paths. Also make sure you're calling `session_start` on both pages before trying to access any session variables.

Comment: I have a basic good understanding of sessions... but just need a little help, youre right maybe I should read more. Anyway, I checked the cookie and it is set and I called session_start on all pages. Any other ideas?

Comment: please? any ideas anyone? the company is getting a bit impatient.... :(

Answer (score 0):

While I am not particularly aware of Chromes behavior regarding Javascript redirects and cookie handling your problem suggests that the session cookie isn't correctly passed onto the serven when you redirect a user via Javascript in Chrome.
To whether this really is the case you could make the session id a part of your redirect, i.e.:

```
window.location = "../submitOrder.php?custid="+custid+"&PHPSESSID="+<?php echo session_id(); ?>;
```

However I think it is unlikely that such issue exists in Chrome, you probably have a mistake in your code (maybe you forgot to use the start_session() function?)

Comment: What kind of error? PHP? Javascript? Chrome? What's the error message?

Comment: thanks for the help :) turns out it was a bad redirect that was messing up the sessions. I changed the redirect to be relative so then works with www. or without.